# Recursivly added information to cells VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am recursively looping through an object. Each node has 3 values. I want to have each row represent the information in a single node. I basically want to put the data into the sheet where the order is in the table below. I can't keep track of a variable because of the recursion.

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 7 | 8 | 9 |
| 10 | 11 | 12 |
| 13 | 14 | 15 |

I am getting JSON as a response to a query.

```
Option Explicit
Dim controlS As Object
Sub p()
Dim key, Keys As Object, JSON As String
JSON = "{""requestId"": ""111111"",""nextTime"": null,""returned"": 6,""scanned"": 12345,""result"": ""[{\""timeS\"":\""2020-02-10\"",\""metric\"":\""Defect\"",\""value\"":403},{\""timeS\"":\""2020-02-10\"",\""metric\"":\""Out\"",\""value\"":3},{\""timeS\"":\""2020-02-10\"",\""metric\"":\""Load\"",\""value\"":6414},{\""timeS\"":\""2020-02-10\"",\""metric\"":\""ZKC\"",\""value\"":959},{\""timeS\"":\""2020-02-10\"",\""metric\"":\""Ops\"",\""value\"":1697},{\""timeS\"":\""2020-02-10\"",\""metric\"":\""SCEX\"",\""value\"":14241}]"",""continuationToken"": null}"
Set controlS = CreateObject("ScriptControl")
controlS.Language = "JScript"

controlS.Eval ("var J = " & JSON)
controlS.Eval ("var R = eval(J.result)")
controlS.AddCode "function k(a){var k=[];for(var b in a){k.push('[\'' + b + '\']');}return k;}"
controlS.AddCode "function t(a){return{}.toString.call(a).slice(8,-1)}"
Set Keys = controlS.Eval("k(R)")
For Each key In Keys
    Call JSONLoop(key)
Next key
End Sub
Private Sub JSONLoop(ByVal key As Variant)
If Not controlS.Eval("t(R" & key & ")") = "Object" And Not controlS.Eval("t(R" & key & ")") = "Array" Then
    Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = controlS.Eval("R" & key) ' This part is the problem
Else
    If Not IsNull(controlS.Eval("R" & key)) = True Then
        Dim key2
        For Each key2 In controlS.Eval("k(R" & key & ")")
        Call JSONLoop(key & key2)
        Next key2
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add your code. [Without code, it is very hard to help you](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/).

Comment: What did you try by your own? We would like to see that problematic 'recursion'... I also must confess that I did not understand anything from your question. That's why a piece of code can help us understand what you mean.

Comment: what is `object` in your code? Please see [mcve]. One line is not enough to understand where the issue is. Also I see no recursion there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a ByRef parameter to keep track of the recursion.

```vb
Sub p()
    Dim key, Keys As Object, JSON As String
    JSON = "{""requestId"": ""111111"",""nextTime"": null,""returned"": 6,""scanned"": 12345,""result"": ""[{\""timeS\"":\""2020-02-10\"",\""metric\"":\""Defect\"",\""value\"":403},{\""timeS\"":\""2020-02-10\"",\""metric\"":\""Out\"",\""value\"":3},{\""timeS\"":\""2020-02-10\"",\""metric\"":\""Load\"",\""value\"":6414},{\""timeS\"":\""2020-02-10\"",\""metric\"":\""ZKC\"",\""value\"":959},{\""timeS\"":\""2020-02-10\"",\""metric\"":\""Ops\"",\""value\"":1697},{\""timeS\"":\""2020-02-10\"",\""metric\"":\""SCEX\"",\""value\"":14241}]"",""continuationToken"": null}"
   
    Set controlS = CreateObject("ScriptControl")
    controlS.Language = "JScript"
    
    controlS.Eval ("var J = " & JSON)
    controlS.Eval ("var R = eval(J.result)")
    controlS.AddCode "function k(a){var k=[];for(var b in a){k.push('[\'' + b + '\']');}return k;}"
    controlS.AddCode "function t(a){return{}.toString.call(a).slice(8,-1)}"
    Set Keys = controlS.Eval("k(R)")
    For Each key In Keys
        Call JSONLoop(key, 0)
    Next key
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub

Private Sub JSONLoop(ByVal key As Variant, ByRef c As Integer)
   
    If Not controlS.Eval("t(R" & key & ")") = "Object" And Not controlS.Eval("t(R" & key & ")") = "Array" Then
        Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, c).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = controlS.Eval("R" & key) ' This part is the problem
    Else
        If Not IsNull(controlS.Eval("R" & key)) = True Then
            Dim key2
            For Each key2 In controlS.Eval("k(R" & key & ")")
                c = c + 1
                Call JSONLoop(key & key2, c)
            Next key2
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```